# What is a more direct translation of もったいぶっちゃって

Tags: translation

Context is Ellie found a comic book she thinks is interesting but then sees she won't be able to know what happens next since it ends with "to be continued." She finishes her rant with 「もったいぶっちゃって」Not sure what these two words mean but I assume it's something along the lines of "What a load of bullshit..." But I'd like a second opinion.

```
エリー：何これ？
ジョエル：おい！寝てたんじゃないのか？
エリー：あのさあ、そうは見えなかったけどこのマンガ結構面白いよ
でも問題がある
ここ
次回に続く
もったいぶっちゃって
ジョエル：どこにあった？
```

Answer (score 4):

You are seeing an intransitive godan verb もったいぶる. This word basically means "to behave in a pretentious manner", "to put on airs", etc. It also means "to leave someone hanging", "to keep something unsaid (in order to draw attention)", "to choose roundabout wordings and avoid getting down to the main point", etc.

> もったいぶっちゃって。
>   It leaves me hanging!